# How to store a secret word?

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm for handling secret words without storing them in clear text or using a reversible encryption?

Necessary operations include

- getting the length of it, so that we can generate indexes
- testing whether the n-th character matches a specific character

Comment: Like RSA? https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)

Comment: That depends on which types of attack you'd like to counter. Does the attacker have access to your OS? Bios? Disk?

Comment: If you can obtain the length _AND_ test the n-th character then a brute-force attack would be trivial

Comment: This seems more like a info security question than an algorithm question.  There's a discussion on partial password hashing here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92018/does-verifying-identity-by-positions-in-passwords-mean-passwords-are-stored-unha

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the n-th character with another character, the encryption becomes easily reversible. An adversary just has to test all characters with all possible values. So in ASCII that will be 256*8=2048 for an 8 character password.

You should normally store a SHA-256 or SHA-512 of the password (possibly prefixed with a random salt) and compare this value against the user inputed value SHA-256/512ed.

You can also repeat the SHA-256/512 operations several thousand times to make attacks more difficult.